# Is this a direct object or prepositional phrase?

Tags: grammar, prepositional-phrases, direct-objects

Sorry if my question is not suitable for this forum. Although a native speaker, I am unfamiliar with grammatical rules in English (which consequently leads to a lack of comprehension in foreign languages...) I have done research on the differences between direct objects and prepositional phrases but still can't seem to determine the grammatical role of "with my gardening" in the following sentence:

> I have been busy with my gardening.

Is it the direct object? A prepositional phrase?

> I enjoy learning about grammar.

-- "about grammar" is the direct object...?

To me, a direct object is something received/given that the verb does in the sentence; whereas, a prep phrase constitutes a location, time, etc usually with a preposition (but this is still unclear to me).

Comment: Your prepositions are a giveaway that you have prepositional phrases, not objects. If you drop a preposition in *weeding my garden* or *enjoy grammar*, you can get an object.

Comment: Your last sentence sums things up correctly.. But it is such common knowledge that PPs can't be objects that I'm surprised you doubted it.

Comment: Thanks for the help; I'll keep a close eye on the presence of prepositions. I also read in another resource that if you remove the direct object from a sentence, the verb doesn't make much sense without it; this could be another way to determine whether it's a D.O. or prep

Answer (score 1):

> To me, a direct object is something received/given that the verb does in the sentence; whereas, a prep phrase constitutes a location, time, etc usually with a preposition (but this is still unclear to me).

The terms "direct object" and "prepositional phrase" denote syntactic roles and do not (*per se*) depend on *meaning.*

So "with my gardening" is a prepositional phrase, as is "about grammar," since they are headed by the prepositions "with" and "about" respectively.